# how to SELECT and remove entry from MYSQL in foreach loop properly

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a foreach loop that pulls a barcode like this

```
foreach($array as $key=>$term) //loop over each term
{
```

Where within the loop it'll run the "pull barcode" function, where it selects a barcode and then applies it to each item within the loop, for example

-- pull barcode

-- item 1, black, small, insert barcode here

-- item 2, black, medium, insert barcode here

-- item 3, black, medium, insert barcode here

-- delete barcode

```
 }
```

OK, I can already see clearly why this doesn't work. What it does currently is it selects a single barcode and applies it to all of the items 1,2, and 3. I need it to select a barcode from the database, apply it to item 1, then delete, and select a new barcode, for each item.

Basically, each item needs a unique barcode, and the way I have designed it, that isn't happening....

I've tried to run the barcode pull & delete between each item, but that yields the same result.

I've designed the "app" like this

1. Input items in form
2. Loop for each variable separated by comma in said form and apply styles and a unique barcode
3. CSV is generated and ready for upload

Everything is working except for pulling unique barcodes.

The barcodes are in their own database, and there is no need to input the generated information into a database, so it's pretty straight forward, 2 databases, 1 for unused barcodes, and 2 for used barcodes - that functionality is working properly as well.

How can I design this loop to pull a unique barcode? I've came up with a few ideas, but when running a few hundred variables at a time, I imagine it would simply take 10x longer than using excel.

Thanks

Comment: $new[$key]  =  barcode($term); can you do print_r($array); so we can see your array

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _"I've came up with a few ideas"_ - And those are?

Comment: Run 2 loops, one to pull barcodes per term and place them in temp, then run the shirt loop afterwards using barcodes from said temp database increasing each by 1.

Or by separating each line into it's own file where the barcode pulls before and after (didnt work).

Comment: print_r results in 

        Array ( [0] => football [1] => basketball [2] => )